# Radius of convergence by two different methods

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to find the radius of convergence of $\sum n^3z^n $.

First method: $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}  = 1$ which give 1 as the answer.

Second method: $ \lim_{n\to\infty}sup (|c_{n}|)^{\frac{1}{n}} = 2^{\frac{3}{2}}$ since $n^{\frac{3}{n}} $ attains maximum value at 2 ($e$ if we consider n to be real and not integer). Hence answer from second method is $2^{\frac{3}{2}}$ .

What am I doing wrong here and thus getting two different answers?

Comment: By suppressing some of the notation you have made an error. $\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n$ is short hand for $\lim_{m \to \infty} \sup_{n \geq m} x_n$. What you wrote would be rather useless because the sup is always just one number anyway, so why would you take the limit of it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are: in the Cauchy Hadamard formula you did something wrong

$$\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n^3}=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt[n]n\right)^3=1^3=1$$

Taking the lim sup is **not** the same as taking the supremum: for example

$$\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}\left\{\,\frac1n\,\right\}_{n\in\Bbb N}=1\;,\;\;\text{yet}\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0$$

In simple words: the $\;\lim sup\;$ of a sequence is the highest partial limit of some subsequence of the sequence, and similarly for the $\;\lim\inf\;$, which is the smallest such partial limit. These two partial limits equal iff **the limit** of the whole sequence exists and equals that common value $\;\lim\sup=\lim\inf\;$. The Cauchy-Hadamard formula refers to the \lim\sup\;$ .

Comment: Could you explain it in a bit more detail? I'm still confused after thinking about it for some time.

Comment: @AnantJoshi Some explanation added.

Comment: Could you explain what a partial limit of some subsequence of the sequence is?

Comment: @AnantJoshi Your question confuses me: this should be old stuff , imo, for someone studying series and power series! Anyway, for example: $$\cos n\pi=(-1)^n\implies$$ this sequence has two pretty obvious subsequences: the one with even indexes and the one with odd ones. The lim sup here is $\;1\;$ , the lim inf is $\;-1\;$ .

Comment: I was referring to what you wrote in your answer "the limsup of a sequence is the highest partial limit of some subsequence of the sequence" . So what is the partial limit of some subsequence of the sequence?

Comment: @AnantJoshi Partial limit = limit of a susequence of a sequence. This should be known if you're dealing with power series...